# Possible ways to bypass UAC if user not in admin group?

Tags: uac

i hate my work devices and other network PC's, All they do is setup password and enable UAC on the all computers, i need to install some application that requires UAC and admin rights as well as my user account not in admin group.
So if there is any possible ways to bypass em if user not in admin group?

Comment: use [portableapps](https://portableapps.com/) instead of installs

Comment: yep i searched if there is portable ones but there is none.

Comment: You are essentially asking how to get admin rights without an admin password, which is explicitely off topic here... If you are is a special use case, please explain it here. If you don't this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: You can also request local admin rights. This is a common way to permit users with laptops to manage their own software without getting rights to domain-wide operations.

Answer (score 4):

Your work computer belongs to your company, not you.  If your boss needs you to install a piece of software to do your job better, have him ask the admins to install it.

If not, **do not try to violate their rules and install it yourself**.

Why not? Because of all the trouble you could be blamed for creating. If the software came with a vulnerability that enables a virus or ransomware infection, your whole company could be at risk. The company's lawyers would hang you out to dry in a heartbeat.

Comment: i see thats some quality advise. but the one thing is at the moment our IT guy, gone in vacation somewhere.. and we can't reach. So otherwise i could just ask him to do it for me. I just want to know that if it's possible since of course my chairman already knows. Thanks for advice.

Comment: That's good context to know, but this group still doesn't provide info on breaking in to specific machines; we provide info on preventing that.